# where place .php file for ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to implement ajax in my codeigniter.
I use it in js like this:

```
data={action:'getstreets'};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../ajax",
    data: data,
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
    {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

And ajax.php is a controller with code like this:

```
<?php
class Ajax extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->database();
        switch($this->input->get_post('action'))
        {
            case "getstreets":
                $query = $this->db->query('SELECT 1;');
                echo 'WIN';
            break;
            default:
                echo "Invalid action";
            break;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Is it proprer way, to use controller for this? Can't hacker somehow get this data?

Comment: wonder what for minus is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codeigniter is MVC framework, and you can't place any .php file. You should have controller and the action in it. Please, look at this.
http://blog.codinghorror.com/understanding-model-view-controller/

Comment: This is exactly what I've done. A controller with actions called ajax.php.

Comment: I asked if it is safe?

Comment: Well, as I understand it's ok to use controller as ajax.php file will approve your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check this one

```
data={action:'getstreets'};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url('ajax/index')?>", //Here I have added code
    data: data,
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
    {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Make sure to load URL helper, otherwise you can write statically like `http://website.com/index.php/ajax/index`

Comment: I have separate js file will it work there? I get exception like 'disallowed key'.

Comment: Then use static url declaration `http://website.com/index.php/ajax/index` and check once

Comment: and what's the point to use ajax/index instead of ajax? Is it more safe?

Comment: not like that just I have mentioned `class/methodname` no need of index because which is default function call in CI